# How much time has passed on Orphan Black from S1-4?

Tags: orphan-black

I'm re-watching Orphan Black and am trying to work out,
 **How much time has passed in each season?**
The only explicit period of time I can recall is when Alison is in rehab, but it's not made clear exactly how long this is for (but it's still only 1 or 2 weeks).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't done a lot of research into this, but here's what I've got so far.

Show starts in late November 2012.
(Sarah withdraws money from Beth's bank account on 11/25/12, a couple of days after Beth's suicide.)

[image: OrphanBlack_S01E01]

Season 2 picks up immediately after the end of season 1, with Sarah just having discovered Kira and S missing.

Season 3 begins pretty shortly after the end of season 2, because Helena is still in transit to the Castor camp.

Season 4 begins in late May 2014.
(Date on Helena's ultrasound in S04E02 is 05/22/2014.)

[image: OrphanBlack_S04E02]

However...

That doesn't really fit with what the producers said in [this interview](http://www.etonline.com/tv/163030_orphan_black_postmortem_scorpion_psychosis_mystery_elevator_clone_more_answers_revealed/) at the start of season 3:

> **Can you clarify the Orphan Black timeline? It's really only been a few
>   weeks since Sarah watched Beth jump in front of that train, correct?**
>
> JF: It's the magic of television time but I think it's only been
>   30-something days. I think we're in our 40 by the end of season three.
>
> GM: Or it might even be two months. It's not a long period of time but
>   it's better to kind of just sink into TV time.
>
> JF: The point of it
>   really is that we like to go fast and we don’t like to take a lot of
>   breaks and it's kind of part of the way our mystery presents is that
>   we don’t really take our foot off the gas for very long.

Nor does it fit what was said in the early episodes of season 4, about how it had been around 2-3 months since the end of season 3 and that Trina, the Neolutionist girl Beth met in the flashbacks to just before her suicide, was about six months pregnant in the flashbacks and now in season 4 had recently given birth.

Also, the fact that Helena is still pregnant in season 4 means not too much time could have passed since she was impregnated in season 2.

So I think the ultrasound date has to be a prop error and we're really circa May 2013 in early season 4.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: A little over a month is certainly the feeling I get watching S1-3, but as you say it doesn't really agree with the pregnancies we see. I wasn't aware of that interview, so it's interesting to see that word-of-god puts it at around that as well.