# What's the timeline for Orphan Black?

Tags: orphan-black

In the final episode of *Orphan Black*, we see Sarah, Kira, and Felix go fishing.

**How much time has passed since Sarah witnessed Beth's suicide in S1E1?**

And for <s>bonus points</s> a bounty, what's the entire timeline for all events, including those seen in flashbacks or photographs?

Comment: I know of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138037/19561), but that's only for the first _four_ seasons and doesn't include earlier events.

Comment: Episode 5x09 establishes a hard timeline between season 2 and pre-time jump: "35 weeks is nearly full term for twins."

Comment: Also, John Fawcett says [the time jump is three months](http://ew.com/tv/2017/08/12/orphan-black-series-finale-creators-burning-questions/).